# Why isn't it a common practice on Windows to symlink executables to C:\Windows\System32?

Tags: linux, windows, path

On linux, it's very common that during the installation of some application, it is created a symbolic link to it's executables in `/usr/bin` so they would be in the system's `PATH` variable.

On the other hand, on Windows, most applications will concatenate it's own installation path to the `PATH` environment variable during it's installation, which lead to a few problems which are not part of this question's scope.

I see the folder `C:\Windows\System32` to have a somewhat similar role to `/usr/bin`, as both are part of the standard `PATH` variable in both systems, so why isn't it a common practice to symlink executables to `C:\Windows\System32`?

Comment: The recommended way to locate an executable in Windows is to use the App Paths Registry subkey, https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ee872121

Comment: The Linux filesystem hierarchy is so different from Windows a comparison of that kind just isn't valid in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Because the `PATH` environment variable predates the symbolic link feature by two decades.** The equivalent of symbolic links as you see in Linux was introduced in 2006 with Windows Vista. The `PATH` variable has existed since 1986.

**To turn away from a 20-years-old approach towards a new one, developers need one hell of a good reason** that outweighs the disadvantages of creating symbolic links in `System32`:

- Doing so needs administrative privileges.
- One symbolic link must be created for each .exe file.
- Installers and uninstallers must create and destroy them. If the developer ever changes the name of its .exe file, he must write a routine to check for old symbolic links and update them.
- Bearing all the above in mind, if two apps turn out to have similarly named .exe files, we will be having a "Symbolic link hell" in addition to the "DLL hell". Isn't one hell enough already?
- The result is always per-machine (not per-user or per-process).

Meanwhile:

- Not many apps use the `PATH` variable anyway. Most apps are GUI apps that install their shortcuts into the Start menu and that their main avenue of execution.
- The `PATH` variable can be customized on a per-machine, per-user and even per-process basis. In fact, some apps like Visual Studio have customized Command Prompts with customized per-process `PATH` variable only for that instance.

Comment: Last part there is the most relevant. Most programs today don't use or need PATH. Some file managers may be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty broad and I'm not not sure it'll survive but the obvious answer is that `System32` is not at all similar to `/usr/bin`. You *said* they play a similar role, but that doesn't make it true. The mere fact that they are both part of the system path doesn't mean they have similar roles.

If anything, `System32` is more similar `/sbin` which is also part of the default system path on Linux. The comparison is far from perfect though as these are very different operating systems.

Is it common practice to put symbolic links to general user-installed programs in `/sbin`?